# Out of all possible configurations of a regular $8\times 8$ chess board, how many configurations are impossible?

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

Given the usual rules and initial configuration of pieces. There are some obvious ones that come to mind, such as any configuration with a pawn on 1 or 8, or all pawns on 2 and anything but a white knight on any square (analogous example for 7/black). Does anyone know of an elegant, combinatorial calculation, rather than a brute force computation?

Comment: If this was known, so would be the number of possible configurations. But it isn't. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00182-014-0453-7

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is, out of all *possible* configurations, there aren't any that are impossible.

Comment: See http://tromp.github.io/chess/chess.html .